# PrimeFaces: row edit data table in data table row expansion

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `p:dataTable` that contains another `p:dataTable` inside a row expansion.

My problem is that I can't edit the inner table since it's in a `p:rowExpansion`

Works fine without a `p:rowExpansion`, will stop where edit icon is not clickable.

```
    <h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Expand rows to see detailed information
        </f:facet>
        <p:column style="width:16px">
            <p:rowToggler />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:rowExpansion>
          <p:dataTable  var="list" value="#{car.list}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px">
       <f:facet name="header">
           Row Editing
       </f:facet>


       <p:column headerText="Id">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{list.id}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{list.id}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column style="width:32px">
           <p:rowEditor />
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
        </p:rowExpansion>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Hi, show your xhtml code

Comment: source code has been edited

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: any one got solution @bob-cal ?